# Rspec controller testing for update of article does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is my controller_spec file portion of relevant code.....

```
login_user
  context 'Update article with valid attributes' do
    it 'Update article'do 
      article = Article.create!(attributes_for(:article))
      put :update, 
          id:article.to_param,
          :article => attributes_for(:article, title: "Title Changed")
      article.reload
      expect(Article.first.title).to eq("Title Changed")
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting this error
Failure/Error: expect(Article.first.title).to eq("Title Changed")

```
   expected: "Title Changed"
        got: "My first post"

   (compared using ==)
```

The controller code of update

```
# ..ArticlesController#update
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: First, make sure you're testing the correct Article by changing to `expect(article.title).to eq("Title Changed")`.

Comment: i dont know why the title is not getting  updated .

Comment: i want to change the article with title "My first post" to "Title changed"?But its not working .Your suggestion returned the same result as the previous on.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code from the update action in your controller?

Comment: How about `put :update, id:article.to_param, :article => {title: "Title Changed"}` ?

Comment: Sorry this also returns the same result

Comment: We can't be of further help unless you show us the controller code.

Comment: Is it the spec that doesn't work or does the action not work in the browser either?

Comment: The controller code of update is provided.

Comment: The destroy method testing is not working.